# I'm using Java Spring framework to map data from a portion of my data and my pathvariable won't get me access to any data

Tags: java, spring

I'm using the Java Spring framework to map data from a portion of my data and my @pathvariable won't get me access to any data. all I;m getting in the console is
`bash: localhost:4001/traveladventures/bycountry/Greece: No such file or directory`

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import java.util.List;

  @GetMapping()
  public Iterable<Adventure> getAllAdventures(){
    return this.adventureRepository.findAll();
  }

  @GetMapping("/bycountry/{country}")
  public List<Adventure> getByCountry(@PathVariable("country") String country){
    return this.adventureRepository.findByCountry(country);
  }
```

my data is comming in through sql and I'm using this interface to get access to the data

```
public interface AdventureRepository extends CrudRepository<Adventure, Integer> {
  public List<Adventure> findByCountry(String country);
  public List<Adventure> findByState(String state);
}
```

Comment: How are you calling the service?

Comment: @pringi  what do you mean I believe I'm using localhost:4001/traveladventures/bycountry/Greece

Comment: That is the URL you are using, but how are you calling that URL?  Are you using `curl` on the command line? Are you trying to load it in your browser? etc

Comment: From the error message it seems that you just enter `localhost:4001/traveladventures/bycountry/Greece` in a shell. This doesn't work - the shell tries to access `localhost:4001/traveladventures/bycountry/Greece` as a file in the local file system and doesn't find it. You need to use `curl localhost:4001/traveladventures/bycountry/Greece`

Comment: it's not a database it's sql: INSERT INTO ADVENTURES (ID, DATE, COUNTRY, CITY, STATE, NUM_PHOTOS, BLOG_COMPLETED) VALUES (350, '03/17/2018', 'Poland', 'Sadowie', '', 5, true); @red

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This command

> Blockquote

curl -v http://localhost:4001/traveladventures/bycountry/Greece

Answer (score 1):

Can you confirm whether you get the value of the country inside this getByCountry()method (by either logging or debugging) or it's not even hitting the API?
Also, please check the path of the API as well. Is the first Get API working?

Also one suggestion, Controller is basically a dumb entry point of the API, all business logic must be implemented in the Service layer. The controller just passes the incoming values to the service layer.

Comment: /traveladventure is working per your request. However it's an sql database by the way INSERT INTO ADVENTURES (ID, DATE, COUNTRY, CITY, STATE, NUM_PHOTOS, BLOG_COMPLETED) VALUES (350, '03/17/2018', 'Poland', 'Sadowie', '', 5, true);

Comment: Great! Any updates on the first question that I've asked?

Comment: how do I log that to the consal